# Spring Data Hibernate + Pageable: Returns empty results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using Spring Data repositories without any problems.
When I tried to add Paging (using the Pageable interface) it worked OK.

However, when the returned result set is less then the Page size, the result is empty List.

The following is my PageRequest. The default values for index and objectsPerPage are 0 and 10 respectively.

```
new PageRequest(pageIndex_, objectsPerPage_, new Sort(orders))
```

When using it with a query that returns less than 10 results, the resulting list is empty.

This is how I use the repository in the Service layer:

```
repository.findAll(MySpecification.searchClients(criteria),
            myPagingSpecification(criteria.getPageIndex(), criteria.getNumberPerPage(), null))
            .getContent();
```

**EDIT 1**
I found the cause of this, however I am still searching for a solution or a workaround.

```
        Long total = QueryUtils.executeCountQuery(getCountQuery(spec));
    List<T> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.getResultList() : Collections.<T> emptyList();
```

This code, located in the `SimpleJpaRepository` class makes `select count...` and if the count is less then the offset, returns an empty list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `PageRequest` implementation:

```
public int getOffset() {
    return page * size;
}
```

so if you set `page` to `0` the `offset` value must also be `0` and cannot be larger than `total` (if `total > 0`).

Check (maybe in debugger) what `pageIndex` value you pass to spring-data.
It may be other value - sometimes it is simple mistake.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the Query parameter from my REST services was `page=1` and I had forgotten that the pages are 0 based, but my API is not.

Comment: I had the same issue, was looking at page = 1 instead of 0... thanks!